# Intellisense in Visual Studio cannot find CUDA cooperative groups namespace

Tags: c++, cuda, intellisense

When working with CUDA cooperative groups, I need to `#include <cooperative_groups.h>` to access the `cooperative_groups` namespace. However, intellisense is unable to see this namespace and I end up with red squiggly lines.

Minimal example code:

```
#include <cooperative_groups.h>

namespace cg = cooperative_groups; // Intellisense does not recognise cooperative_groups here

int main() {
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine (as do any of the cooperative groups examples), so it's just an issue with intellisense being unable to find the namespace.

Comment: `#include <cooperative_groups.h>` -> `#include "cooperative_groups.h"` maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the `cooperative_groups.h` header file, it appears that the entire namespace is wrapped in `#if defined(__cplusplus) && defined(__CUDACC__)`. When intellisense attempts to parse the header file, `__CUDACC__` is not defined (this is defined by nvcc), so it cannot find the namespace. My solution was to wrap `#include <cooperative_groups.h>` in conditional `#define`s for intellisense:

```cpp
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#define __CUDACC__
#endif // __INTELLISENSE__

#include <cooperative_groups.h>

#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#undef __CUDACC__
#endif // __INTELLISENSE__
```

Now intellisense can properly parse the header file, and performs syntax highlighting as you would expect. Tested in Visual Studio 2022, with the minimal example above and the [Simple Cooperative Groups example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/simpleCooperativeGroups).